# Help with power analyses - adjusting alpha level correctly

Tags: multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, false-discovery-rate, familywise-error

I will be conducting a series of ANCOVAs and MANCOVAs for a 2 x 3 x 3 design with 2 covariates (1 covariate will only be relevant for a subset of analyses). There are 9 main DVs in the study. Three of these main DVs will happen after principal component analysis of a set of files reviewed by the participants (so could have MANCOVAs looking at 2 factors in a DV or *n* factors depending on what comes out). Thinking about which tests are likely to be related, there should be 3 DVs related to each other and another 4 related to each other with the remaining 3 DVs each tapping different constructs. I've been looking in k-FWER and FDR as well as considering more traditional methods like Bonferroni adjustment, but I'm not sure which to use. I'm trying to do my power analyses using G*Power, so I'm trying to figure out which adjusted alpha level to use. I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Are you committed to a Bonferroni-like adjustment? Its not really necessary if you lay out your research plan a priori and stick to the plan.

Comment: Our grant reviewers wanted us to adjust for testing multiple hypotheses; they were not happy with the original power analyses done.

Comment: What is your resesrch hypothesis with regard to all the factors mentioned? Are some factors for adjusting? Is there a natural ordering to the exposure you are examining?

Comment: We think there will be similar patterns for all of the DVs. We basically have people reviewing files, so we are looking at the number of files they review, the average order in which they review the files, the amount of time reviewing the files, etc. Then we are looking at their actual opinions about the information in the files. We are manipulating their expectations before seeing the files to see if that changes their info search, and we are manipulating the information in some of the files to see if it changes how long they spend looking at files and their opinions about the information.